# Setup mysql query with dynamic datasets per section

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

Ok, so my main issue is with anything that goes between WHERE and ORDER BY, LIMIT, etc.

I have it currently setup like the below:

```
SELECT " . $column_string . " FROM " . $table_name . " " . $query_join . " " . $where . " " . $query_end . " " . $query_limit
```

My issue is this, I have it setup to check each variable with escape string but when you come to $query_end which would hold test = '1' AND test2 = '2' etc. I have that section setup to allow you to send the whole string in one go. But of course if you check that it gets turned into test = \'1\' AND test2 = \'2\'.

The only thing I could think of doing was seperating it into some wierd array like [test2 = ],[2] but that doesn't work for (test1 = '2' OR test2 = '3') although I could make it work I really don't want to do it that way.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to the above problem? Also is there another item for checking for injection outside of mysql-real-escape-string?

The whole reason for this setup is to allow me to send multiple queries via ajax using json and then sending all the data back in a 3 level array.

Comment: I doubt you'll get any reasonable answers to this question. You're talking about your own custom set up where you've coded yourself to automatically escape every variable. Obviously you need to modify your custom code/library to allow specific variables to be passed through unescaped. As you do not appear to be using a known framework or library, and have not posted your custom code that shows how your escaping mechanism works, it is not possible to recommend specific changes or workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing actually wrong with "weird" array.

Every custom search solution is based on the similar approach - a series of conditions to assembly a WHERE clause dynamically.
I have no idea though, why would you need a fieldset or a table set by a user. But the idea would be quite the same. Just don't forget to verify all the identifiers and operators against a hardcoded white list.

Comment: I just figured there would be sometihng outside of escape that could also defend against injection but I've never seen anything.